# how do i keep my while loop going, until the player inputs the answer to progress?

Tags: python, input, while-loop, return

```
sub_choice_1 = input("1.yes\n2.no\n> ")
valid_3_2 = True
while valid_3_2:
      if sub_choice_1 == "2":
            print("\"well keep me updated:)\"")
            break
      elif sub_choice_1 == "1":
            print("\"was it blair as i suspected\"\n")
            sub_choice_2 = input("1.I haven't quite figured it out yet, i still have some questions to ask her\n"
                                 "2.i think you took it.\n")
            valid_3_2_2 = True
            while valid_3_2_2:
                  if sub_choice_2 == "1":
                        print("\"well keep me updated:)\"")
                        break
                  elif sub_choice_2 == "2":
                        print("\"What a preposterous claim, I was in my cottage as I said, and until you have\n"
                              "evidence of the contrary you can keep your accusations to yourself.\"\n")
                        m_1_redundancy = True
                        break
                  else:
                        print("your mumbo jumbo is not to my understanding, please rephrase\n")
            break
      else:
            print("your mumbo jumbo is not to my understanding, please rephrase\n")
```

what I want is for both while loops to continue if the player, does not input either "1" or "2" as an answer. if they dont they should get the (else) message and the question should be re asked.

but when I run itm, the else statement goes on forever. i have tried to return, but get the "return out of function" error, and have also tried to "continue" but it doesn't stop it from endlessly printing the (else) print.

Comment: The "input" calls must be in the respective while-loops (near the beginning), not before them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `input()` functions inside the loop otherwise the values can never be updated.  Aside from there, here's my suggestion, which I hope helps a little, at least.  I'm breaking out of the `while` loops earlier, which prevents them from being nested.

```
while True:
    sub_choice_1 = input("1.yes\n2.no\n> ")
    if sub_choice_1 not in ['1', '2']:
        print("your mumbo jumbo is not to my understanding, please rephrase\n")
    else:
        break

if sub_choice_1 == "2":
    print("\"well keep me updated:)\"")
elif sub_choice_1 == "1":  
    print("\"was it blair as i suspected\"\n")
    
    while True:
        sub_choice_2 = input("1.I haven't quite figured it out yet, i still have some questions to ask her\n"
                            "2.i think you took it.\n")
        if sub_choice_2 not in ['1', '2']:
            print("your mumbo jumbo is not to my understanding, please rephrase\n")
        else:
            break

    if sub_choice_2 == "1":
        print("\"well keep me updated:)\"")
    elif sub_choice_2 == "2":
        print("\"What a preposterous claim, I was in my cottage as I said, and until you have\n"
                "evidence of the contrary you can keep your accusations to yourself.\"\n")
        m_1_redundancy = True
```